# Effectively create adjecency matrix from lists of neighbors from multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, adjacency-matrix

I have a large collection of CSVs, each containing

- an "`id`" column of values, and
- a "`neighbors`" column with lists of strings.

Values from `id` do not occur in any `neighbors` lists. Values in `id` are unique per CSV, no CSV contains all the `id` values, and if two CSV share an `id` value, then the rows refer to the same object.

I would like to create something akin to a bipartite adjacency matrix from these CSVs, with a row for each each `id` value `i`, a column for each `neighbors` string `j`, and a `1` in cell `(i,j)` if there in any of the CSVs exists a row with `id` value `i` where  string `j` occurs in the `neighbors` list.

The code below does what it's supposed to, but it takes very long.

Is there a more effective way of getting the job done?

```
import pandas as pd
adjacency_matrix = pd.DataFrame()
list_of_csv_files = [csv_file1, csv_file2, ...]

for file in list_of_csvs:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.set_index('id', inplace = True)

    for i in df.index:
        for j in df.at[i,'neighbors']:
            adjacency_matrix.at[i, j] = 1
```

**Example:**

Given that the csvs are loaded to the list `list_of_dataframes = [df1,df2]` with

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['11','12'], 'N': [['a'], ['a', 'b']]})

    id  neighbors
0   11  [a]
1   12  [a, b]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['11','13'], 'N': [['c'], ['d']]})

    id  neighbors
0   11  [c]
1   13  [d]
```

I seek the dataframe

```
    a   b   c   d
11  1   NaN 1   NaN
12  1   1   NaN NaN
13  NaN NaN NaN 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a cleaner and efficient way using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_csv_files = [csv_file1, csv_file2, ...]
list_of_dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_csv_files]
out = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
out = out.explode('neighbors').drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
out.set_index('id', inplace=True)
out = pd.get_dummies(out, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
out = out.groupby('id').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you. I seem to loose the connection to the `id` values now, though, which I previously kept by writing them to the row index. Is it possible to do something similar here?

Comment: I updated the answer. please check.

Comment: Thank you. I've tested, and now added an example to be more clear (my apologies). When I try it on the dataframes of the example, `out` is returned correctly for `12` and `13`, but incorrectly for `11`,  which misses an entry in column `c`.

Comment: Ok, that helped. Always give sample examples :) please try the code now.